# Akka Deprecated Warnign [Props] Play Framework 2.2.X

Tags: java, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

I´m not really keen on Akka, mainly because I don´t really need it that much, but I used to use some code that always work for me:

```
@Override
  public void onStart(Application app) {
      ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(new Props(Retreiver.class));
      Akka.system()
      .scheduler()
      .schedule(Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
              Duration.create(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS), myActor, "TICK",
              Akka.system().dispatcher(),null);
  }
```

The thing is that in current Play it gives a Warning with a Deprecation in the Props part, it seems to be working fine but I would like to know how it´s the correct way to do it in the current Play.

Thanks for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation:

[http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.2.4/akka/actor/Props.html#Props(java.lang.Class)](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.2.4/akka/actor/Props.html#Props%28java.lang.Class%29)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is the correct form in this version (taken from the docs suggested)

```
@Override
  public void onStart(Application app) {
      ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(Retreiver.class));
      Akka.system()
      .scheduler()
      .schedule(Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
              Duration.create(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS), myActor, "TICK",
              Akka.system().dispatcher(),null);

  }
```